# Possible GHMM extension

Tags: python, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I am really enjoying playing around with the [GHMM](http://ghmm.org/) library.  I was wondering if there is anyway to define custom emission distributions with matrix parameters.  Specifically, I was looking to do the following:

I would like to use a modified version of the `ghmm.MultivariateGaussianDistribution` setup.  However, instead of allowing for a Multivariate normal with a full covariance matrix, where each distribution state has n^2 + n parameters (n being the dimension of the emission variables), I was hoping to constrain the distribution to a multivariate normal with zero non-diagonal parameters (i.e. where each emission variable is independent of the others, but they are drawn together depending on the state i).  Thus, the parameters are reduced to 2n for each state.  This, should really improve the estimation of the diagonal variance terms, which are most important, in situations where there is not too much data points to work with.

Any guidance on where to modify the code would be appreciated.